Can a ML model learn the hyperparameters landscape?
(I assume that this is not possible because I've never seen anyone talk about this.)
Let's take a classic MLP (named f) that, for example classify some images (from a dataset D). This MLP have some hyperparameters H like the learning rate.
Is it possible to have another ML model g that, based on the dataset Dand the f model architecture, could tell the optimal hyperparameters H* (for example to use the optimal learning rate without any gridsearch) ?
Summarized as :  g(D,f) = H*
Of course this question can be extended as : why don't we make a model that can learn to predict the best weight of the model directly with as input the dataset D and the model architecture f ?

this is related to meta-learning. you might find this paper interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04474

In general a ML model g as you specified needs training dataset and hyperparameters for itself, therefore you're still facing the same type of problems in the meta-level and it's computational expensive or infeasible to prepare a representative training and test datasets for g with satisfactory generalization error.
Having said that, there's some related research such as neural architecture search (NAS) to achieve similar based on differentiable objectives to gradually optimize architectures and hyperparameters.

Neural architecture search (NAS) is a technique for automating the design of artificial neural networks (ANN), a widely used model in the field of machine learning... NAS is closely related to hyperparameter optimization and meta-learning and is a subfield of automated machine learning (AutoML)

